# Failing Release build (Linker, ___gxx_personality_v0")

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

Using react-native v0.40

I've tried creating a Release build to run my application offline on my phone, but this resulted in following errors (app runs in simulator after failed build, but won't start on my phone)

[image]

---

After several google queries and stackoverflow ones, I am still not able to solve this.

**UPDATE:**
The build target for these errors is my projectTest one created by react-native i.e. it creates 2 targets in xCode project and projectTest, I am not sure what this test one is for, explanation on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After react-native issue research I was able to find a solution via this comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2685#issuecomment-268314997

You need to set other flags to your test target, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: omg .. it compile flutter ios plugin without #use_frameworks